# Bash script errors out; there are '\r' characters in the execution trace

Tags: bash, shell, sh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to make a litte script that syncs my project directory with a shared git repo more or less automatically. However I just don't seem to get the first line right. So in theory this should be fine:

```
#!/bin/bash
rsync -trnv /mnt/d/project/bundle/ /mnt/d/bundle/ --exclude=".git" --delete
cd /mnt/d/bundle/
git add .
read -p "" msg
git commit -m $msg
git push origin master
cd "${0%/*}"
```

The script fails, afaik, because it ignores the second option of the rsync command completely. Moreover it can't find the directory, which is an absolute path and exists. See:

```
$ bash -x ptmrbundle-rsync.sh
+ rsync -trnv /mnt/d/bundle/ /mnt/d/project/bundle/ --exclude=.git $'--delete\r' rsync: --delete\#015: unknown option rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1572) [client=3.1.1]
+ cd $'/mnt/d/bundle/\r' : No such file or directory: cd: /mnt/d/bundle/
```

Note: working on linux subsystem for windows.

So the rows of commands work just fine in the shell itselt, but when used in the .sh script if complettely fails. What's the matter?

Comment: It even says explicitly `$'--delete\r'` - you have DOS-style carriage returns in your script. Run `dos2unix` or tell your editor to stop using the wrong line ending style.

Comment: Did you mean "Windows Subsystem for Linux" (WSL)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line Endings are different on Windows or Linux.

Considering a file

```
Line A
Line B
Libe C
```

On Windows it will actually be like

```
Line A\r\n
Line B\r\n
Libe C\r\n
```

And on Linux it will be like

```
Line A\n
Line B\n
Libe C\n
```

As you can see there is a difference on how the end of a line is defined.

Apparently, you saved your file with Windows Line Ending `\r\n` so as Linux does not "care" about `\r` it assumes it's part of the script you are coding... so you are actually executing

```
#!/bin/bash\r
rsync -trnv /mnt/d/project/bundle/ /mnt/d/bundle/ --exclude=".git" --delete\r
cd /mnt/d/bundle/\r
git add .\r
read -p "" msg\r
git commit -m $msg\r
git push origin master\r
cd "${0%/*}"\r
```

and that will lead to various problems.

To solve this open the file in an editor and change the line endings.

e.g. in Notepad++

1. Open File
2. Edit -> Eol Conversion -> Unix (LF)
3. Save File